# ruby on rails - fixture_file_upload not working with controller tests for CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, minitest

I'm having a problem with my controller integration tests on my ROR 5.2 project using CarrierWave and Minitest. I'm using fixture_file_upload to "upload" a file, which works correctly in my model tests, but fails in my controller integration tests due to the presence validation of the CarrierWave property in my model. It *always* fails on the create action. The update action occasionally and randomly fails too, even though I didn't update the CarrierWave property.

I used byebug to check the value of the property on the create action and it returns nothing; the property is never set. I also checked the errors of the newly created model and they are: "Icon can't be blank".

fixture_file_upload works fine in my model tests, and doing the creating/updating/uploading manually (not in tests) works fine too.

I've Googled for many hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but everything I find says to use fixture_file_upload, and I haven't found anything related to the problem I'm having.

CarrierWave initializer:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    #To let CarrierWave work on heroku
    config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
    config.cache_dir = 'uploads/tmp'

    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
        config.storage = :file

        #config for tests is done in test/test_helper.rb
    else
        config.storage = :fog

        config.fog_credentials = { #Configuration for Amazon S3
            provider: 'AWS',
            aws_access_key_id: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id],
            aws_secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key],
            region: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:region]
        }

        config.fog_public = false
        config.fog_directory = Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket_name]
        config.fog_host = "#{Rails.application.credentials.aws[:asset_url]}/#{Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket_name]}"
    end
end
```

Test helper:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess #for fixture_file_upload

module UsersHelper
    def login_as(user)
        get login_user_url
        assert_response :success

        post user_login_url(session: { username: user.username, password: 'test1234' }) #have to hard code password here since passwords are stored encrypted
        assert_redirected_to root_url, 'Login did not redirect'
    end

    def logout
        get user_logout
    end
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
    fixtures :all
    # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    include UsersHelper
end

#setup carrierwave for tests
carrierwave_root = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'test', 'support', 'carrierwave')
carrierwave_template = Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files')

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.root = carrierwave_root
    config.cache_dir = carrierwave_root.join('carrierwave_cache')
    config.enable_processing = false
end

#copy carrierwave fixture files to carrierwave root
puts 'Copying CarrierWave fixture files..'
puts carrierwave_template.join('uploads')
puts carrierwave_root
FileUtils.cp_r carrierwave_template.join('uploads'), carrierwave_root

Minitest.after_run do
    #remove carrierwave files
    puts 'Deleting CarrerWave fixture files...'

    Dir.glob(Pathname.new(carrierwave_root).join('*')).each do |dir|
        FileUtils.remove_entry(dir)
    end

    puts 'Cleaning CarrierWave cached files...'
    CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!(0)
end
```

Model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 30 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :slug, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 30 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :icon, presence: true
end
```

IconUploader:

```
class IconUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    after :remove, :delete_empty_upstream_dirs

    def store_dir
        "#{base_store_dir}/#{model.id}"
    end

    def base_store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}"
    end

    #override file name, for uniqueness
    def filename
        random_token = SecureRandom.hex(6/2) #length of 6 characters
        token_var = "@#{mounted_as}_secure_token" #get token variable name
        token = model.instance_variable_get(token_var) #get token from token variable name
        token ||= model.instance_variable_set(token_var, random_token) #if token isn't already set, set it

        @name ||= "#{token}_#{super}" if original_filename.present? and super.present? #create name, using instance variable so token isn't changed (function is called multiple times)
    end

    #set size limits
    def size_range
        1.kilobyte..256.kilobytes #1 kilobyte to 256 kilobytes
    end

    #resize image if width or height is greater than 256px, add padding if needed
    process resize_and_pad: [256, 256] #don't use resize_to_fit, as it adds a white background at least to SVG images

    # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
    # For images you might use something like this:
    def extension_whitelist
        %w(jpg jpeg png svg)
    end

    #whitelist of content types
    def content_type_whitelist
        /image\// #whitelist images
    end

    private

    #delete directory if it's empty
    def delete_empty_upstream_dirs
        path = ::File.expand_path(store_dir, root)
        Dir.delete(path) #fails if path not empty dir

        path = ::File.expand_path(base_store_dir, root)
        Dir.delete(path) #fails if path not empty dir
    rescue SystemCallError => e
        Rails.logger.error(e.message) #log error

        true #nothing, the dir is not empty
    end
end
```

Controller create action:

```
def create
    data = params.require(:category).permit([ :name, :icon, :icon_cache ])

    @category = Category.new(data)

    if @category.save
        flash.notice = 'Category successfully created.'
        redirect_to categories_path
    else
        render :add #show errors
    end
end
```

Controller test:

```
test "should post category_create when admin" do
    login_as(users(:admin))

    get add_category_url
    assert_response :success

    icon = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'category_icon.svg'))

    #fails: validation error: "Icon can't be blank"
    post category_create_url(category: { name: 'test901', icon: icon, icon_cache: '' })
    assert_redirected_to categories_url
    assert_equal 'Category successfully created.', flash[:notice]
end
```

Model test:

```
test "should save when all details correct" do
    category = Category.new(name: 'tools',
            icon: fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'category_icon.svg')))

    #succeeds
    assert category.save, 'Not saved when all details correct: ' + category.errors.full_messages.to_s
end
```

Comment: Have you found a resolution? I spent all day dealing with the same issue.

Comment: ruby optional parens for the win. ‍♂️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
post category_create_url(category: { name: 'test901', icon: icon, icon_cache: '' })
```

should be

```
post category_create_url, params: {category: { name: 'test901', icon: icon, icon_cache: '' }}
```

The first is sending params to the route_helper and results in an attempt to pass the file through query string parameters which won't work.

The second sends params to the post method which correctly posts the params as multipart/form data which will correctly post the file object to the controller.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!
Note: fixture_file_upload does not infer MIME types, so if you're using content_type_whitelist you'll need to add the MIME type as a second parameter to fixture_file_upload, like so: fixture_file_upload 'path/to/file', 'mime/type'